# Как сериализовать объект в php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Accessor 
{
public $arr = [];//

public function __sleep()
{
//Сериализация.
}
public function __wakeup()
{
//Десериализация.
}
}

$obj = new Accessor;
$obj->arr = [1, 2, 3];
$blago = serialize($obj);
echo $blago;
?>
```

Как не пробовал, объект не сериализуется. Что я не понимаю?

Comment: Как это ты вдруг устанавливаешь private-свойство снаружи класса?

Comment: @u_mulder исправил, можешь подсказать что должно быть в __sleep?

Comment: вы, вероятно, несколько заблуждаетесь в том что происходит. Чтобы сериализовать объект и десериализовать обратно не надо переопределять методы sleep/wakeup. Это методы, которые могут быть реализованы для некоторого дополнительного функционала, но для работы самой сериализации они не нужны.

Comment: @teran но вообще в `__sleep` можно указать названия пропертей, которые будут использованы при сериализации, при условии если пропертя private\protected.

Comment: @u_mulder хаха пропертя,над взять на вооружение